# what is the Function return In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've watched some videos and they said "Functions always return value!!". If we don't use the return element, then what does it return instead? Like the function below:

```
function Foo(){
    var x = 4.
    y =5;
    z = x + y;
}
x = Foo();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Couldn't you test it in your own browser before asking the question ? most browser that include a console object have a webinspector/javascript debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should return an 'undefined' property when it is called with *x*

There is generally two scenario:

```
// 1
console.log(x)

// 2
console.log(x())
```

In scenario 1 (which is depicted in your example), it will return a reference of the function (which can be used to execute later).
In scenario 2, it will **executes** the function and return an undefined property.
[Do check out this website if to know more](http://jszen.blogspot.my/2008/07/function-reference-vs-function-call.html)

[undefined is a property of the **global object,** i.e. it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of undefined is the **primitive value** undefined.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Answer (score 2):

Without a `return` statement, a function will return `undefined`.